# XML to JSON convertion loose some XML tags

Tags: java, xml, xmlserializer, json

I'm converting a `XML` string to `JSONObject` using following method:

```
XMLSerializer xml = new XMLSerializer();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) xml.read(input);
```

but after the conversion happened some tags are not included in `JSONObject`. missing tags are exactly the same tags that included in `JSONObject` the only difference is attributes inside the tags are different. can someone tell me what is happening with the conversion.

here are the tag that includes in `JSON`

```
<entry urlName="Dir"
utf8Name="Dir"
type="directory"
changeTimeMilliseconds="1373284160872.00"
changeTimeString="2013-07-08T17:19:20+0530"
state="created"/>
```

and this is the tag skip from convertion

```
<entry urlName="c_samples.zip"
utf8Name="c_samples.zip"
type="object"
size="453"
hashScheme="SHA-256"
hash="9AAA2B203F75ED679F133C1A26BA9BB04CF12466DF0670DEC3CD587ED5FF0A27"
retention="1438317494"
retentionString="7/31/2015 10:08AM"
retentionClass=""
ingestTime="1375244240"
ingestTimeString="7/31/2013 9:47AM"
hold="false"
shred="true"
dpl="1"
index="false"
customMetadata="true"
customMetadataAnnotations="default;453"
version="88015631368193"
replicated="false"
changeTimeMilliseconds="1375260472887.00"
changeTimeString="2013-07-31T14:17:52+0530" 
owner="owner"
domain=""
hasAcl="false"
state="created"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution from changing converting method. earlier I used `net.sf.json.JSONObject` to create the `JSONObject` and `net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer` to do the convertion. I switched to `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.XML` and used

```
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(input);
```

method. it gave me the complete set of tags I want to convert. :)